# JAVA Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm using a open source launcher for minecraft and i'm trying to edit it but is a little bit difficult.
I distribute my launcher trought all the people and half of them have this problem of NullPointer, the rest runs it well. The launcher starts but then, where it is supposed to be the modpack icon there is nothing. I checked that it wasn't a problem of URL of firewall and infact in the console log it's written this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.modpack.ModPackUtils.analyzePacks(ModPackUtils.java:82)
 at it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.modpack.ThreadGetPacksInfo.run(ModPackUtils.java:34)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The Modpack.utils

```
package it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.modpack;

import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.GameLauncher;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.Launcher;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.LauncherLogger;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.Settings;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.utils.DirUtils;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.utils.DirUtils.OS;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.utils.FileUtils;
import it.planetgeeks.mclauncher.utils.LanguageUtils;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author PlanetGeeks
 * 
 */

class ThreadGetPacksInfo implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ModPackUtils.analyzePacks();
    }
}

public class ModPackUtils
{
    public static ArrayList<ModPack> modPacks = new ArrayList<ModPack>();
    public static EnumFilterType filter = EnumFilterType.ALL;
    public static String filterStr = null;
    public static ArrayList<ModPack> filteredList = new ArrayList<ModPack>();
    public static ModPack selected = null;
    public static boolean updatePaused = false;
    public static boolean updateStopped = false;
    private static ArrayList<ModPackFile> downloadList;
    private static int nextIndex = 0;
    private static int downloaded = 0;
    private static int threads = Settings.downloadThreads;
    private static boolean blocked = false;

    public static void startLoading()
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadGetPacksInfo());
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void analyzePacks()
    {
        modPacks = new ArrayList<ModPack>();
        filter = EnumFilterType.ALL;
        filterStr = null;
        filteredList = new ArrayList<ModPack>();
        selected = null;

        try
        {
            ArrayList<String> urls = getUrls();

            if (urls != null)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++)
                {
                    ModPack currentPack = getPack(false, urls.get(i));
                    if (currentPack != null)
                    {
                        addModPack(currentPack);
                    }
                    Launcher.getLauncherFrame().mainPanel.updateModPacks(modPacks, i != urls.size() - 1 ? false : true);

                    //Thread.sleep(1);
                }

                if (modPacks.size() > 0)
                {
                    LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.INFO, "Loaded " + modPacks.size() + " modpacks!");
                }
                else
                {
                    LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.INFO, "No modpack loaded!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File[] list = DirUtils.getWorkingDirectory().listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    File current = list[i];
                    if (current.isDirectory() && !current.getName().equals("launcher"))
                    {
                        ModPack pack = getPack(true, current.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (pack != null)
                        {
                            addModPack(pack);
                        }
                        while(!Launcher.loaded)
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        Launcher.getLauncherFrame().mainPanel.updateModPacks(modPacks, true);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static ModPack getPack(boolean local, String url)
    {
        String packName = null;
        String packOwner = null;
        String packMcVersion = null;
        String packServerLink = null;
        ImageIcon imgIcon = null;
        ArrayList<String> mods = new ArrayList<String>();
        String setup = new String();
        String setupIndex = null;
        boolean serverLinkDirect = false;
        String packBgLink = null;
        String modsListLink = null;
        String packVersion = null;
        String mainClass = null;
        String tweakClass = null;
        File modpack = null;
        if (local)
        {
            File[] list = (new File(url)).listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                if (list[i].getName().endsWith(".modpack"))
                {
                    modpack = list[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (modpack == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            modpack = new File(local ? url : DirUtils.getLauncherDirectory() + File.separator + "temp");
        }

        if (modpack.exists() && !local)
        {
            modpack.delete();
        }
        if (local || FileUtils.downloadFile(url, modpack))
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(modpack));
                String readed = br.readLine();
                while (readed != null)
                {
                    if (readed.startsWith("name="))
                    {
                        packName = readed.substring(5);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("owner="))
                    {
                        packOwner = readed.substring(6);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("version="))
                    {
                        packVersion = readed.substring(8);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("mcVersion="))
                    {
                        packMcVersion = readed.substring(10);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("serverLink="))
                    {
                        packServerLink = readed.substring(11);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("mods="))
                    {
                        if (local)
                        {
                            File[] list = modpack.getParentFile().listFiles();
                            for (int a = 0; a < list.length; a++)
                            {
                                if (list[a].getName().endsWith(".list"))
                                {
                                    modsListLink = readed.substring(5);
                                    mods = FileUtils.readFileContent(true, list[a].getAbsolutePath());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            modsListLink = readed.substring(5);
                            mods = FileUtils.readFileContent(false, modsListLink);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("image="))
                    {
                        packBgLink = readed.substring(6);
                        Image image = null;
                        if (local)
                        {
                            File[] list = modpack.getParentFile().listFiles();
                            for (int a = 0; a < list.length; a++)
                            {
                                if (list[a].getName().endsWith(".png"))
                                {
                                    image = ImageIO.read(list[a]);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            image = ImageIO.read(new URL(packBgLink));
                        }

                        if (image != null)
                        {
                            imgIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("setup="))
                    {
                        setup = readed.substring(6);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("setup-index="))
                    {
                        setupIndex = readed.substring(12);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("serverLink-direct="))
                    {
                        serverLinkDirect = (readed.substring(18).trim()).equals("true") ? true : false;
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("mainClass="))
                    {
                        mainClass = readed.substring(10);
                    }
                    else if (readed.startsWith("tweakClass="))
                    {
                        tweakClass = readed.substring(11);
                    }

                    readed = br.readLine();
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.GRAVE, "Error on reading modpack info!");
                if (!local)
                    modpack.delete();
                return null;
            }
            if (!local)
                modpack.delete();
        }
        else
        {
            LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.GRAVE, "Error on downloading modpack info! URL : '" + url + "'");
            return null;
        }

        ModPack returned = new ModPack(packMcVersion, packName, packOwner, packServerLink);
        returned.setModList(mods);
        returned.setPackImage(imgIcon);
        returned.setSetupLink(setup);
        returned.setSetupIndex(setupIndex);
        returned.setServerLinkDirect(serverLinkDirect);
        returned.setModPackLink(url);
        returned.setPackBgLink(packBgLink);
        returned.setModsListLink(modsListLink);
        returned.setMainClass(mainClass);
        returned.setTweakClass(tweakClass);
        returned.setPackVersion(packVersion);

        return returned;
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> getUrls()
    {   
        if (!FileUtils.internetConnected(Settings.modpacks))
        {
            return null;
        }
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        File modpacks = new File(DirUtils.getLauncherDirectory() + File.separator + "modpacks.list");
        if (modpacks.exists())
        {
            modpacks.delete();
        }
        if (FileUtils.downloadFile(Settings.modpacks, modpacks))
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(modpacks));
                String readed = br.readLine();
                while (readed != null)
                {
                    urls.add(readed);
                    readed = br.readLine();
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.GRAVE, "Error on reading modpack list!");
                return null;
            }
            modpacks.delete();
        }
        else
        {
            LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.GRAVE, "Error on downloading modpack list! URL : '" + Settings.modpacks + "'");
            return null;
        }
        return urls;
    }

    private static void addModPack(ModPack pack)
    {
        if (pack != null)
        {
            modPacks.add(pack);
        }
        else
        {
            LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.GRAVE, "Impossible to add a null pack to modPack list!");
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<ModPack> getFilteredList(ArrayList<ModPack> inputList, EnumFilterType filter, String str)
    {
        ArrayList<ModPack> returned = new ArrayList<ModPack>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++)
        {
            ModPack current = inputList.get(i);

            if (current != null)
            {
                if (filter == EnumFilterType.ALL)
                {
                    return inputList;
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.MCVERSION)
                {
                    if (current.mcVersion.contains(str))
                        returned.add(current);
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.PACKNAME)
                {
                    if (current.packName.contains(str))
                        returned.add(current);
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.PACKOWNER)
                {
                    if (current.packOwner.contains(str))
                        returned.add(current);
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.HASSERVER)
                {
                    if (current.packServerLink != null && !current.packServerLink.equals(""))
                        returned.add(current);
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.HASMOD)
                {
                    if (current.containMod(str))
                        returned.add(current);
                }
                else if (filter == EnumFilterType.DOWNLOADED)
                {
                    if (current.getModPackDir().exists())
                        returned.add(current);
                }
            }
        }

        return returned;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ModPack> getAllPacks()
    {
        return modPacks;
    }

    private static void loadLatestSetup(ModPack modpack)
    {
        File f = new File(modpack.getModPackDir() + File.separator + "setup.settings");

        if (f != null && f.isFile())
        {
            ArrayList<String> lines = FileUtils.readFileContent(true, f.getAbsolutePath());

            ArrayList<String> onlySavePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String l : lines)
            {
                l = l.split(":")[1] != null ? l.split(":")[1] : "null";

                String[] str = l.split("/");

                String path = modpack.getModPackDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "files";

                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
                {
                    path += File.separator + str[i];
                }

                onlySavePaths.add(path);
            }

            for (String l : onlySavePaths)
            {
                boolean exists = false;
                for (ModPackFile s : modpack.setup)
                {
                    if (l.equals(s.getSaveFile().getAbsolutePath()))
                    {
                        exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!exists)
                {
                    File fi = new File(l);
                    if (fi.exists())
                    {
                        fi.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setupModPack(final ModPack modpack)
    {
        blocked = false;

        Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(true);

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Launcher.getLauncherFrame().southPanel.updateStatus(-1, "", 100, 100, 100);
                modpack.setSetup(FileUtils.readFileContent(false, modpack.setupLink));
                loadLatestSetup(modpack);
                FileUtils.downloadFile(modpack.setupLink, new File(modpack.getModPackDir() + File.separator + "setup.settings"));
                if (ModPackUtils.updateStopped)
                {
                    updateStopped = false;
                    Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(false);
                    return;
                }
                while (updatePaused)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        if (updateStopped)
                        {
                            updateStopped = false;
                            Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(false);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }

                if (modpack.setup != null)
                {
                    downloadList = new ArrayList<ModPackFile>();

                    check: for (int i = 0; i < modpack.setup.size(); i++)
                    {

                        if (updateBlocked())
                        {
                            downloadList.clear();
                            threads = 0;
                            blocked = true;
                            break check;
                        }

                        ModPackFile current = modpack.setup.get(i);

                        File currentFile = current.getSaveFile();

                        if (currentFile.exists())
                        {
                            Launcher.getLauncherFrame().southPanel.updateStatus(2, currentFile.getName(), -1, i + 1, modpack.setup.size());
                            if (Launcher.forceUpdate || (current.check() && !(current.getMD5().equals(FileUtils.generateBufferedHash(currentFile)) && current.getSize().equals(FileUtils.getFileSize(currentFile)))))
                            {
                                currentFile.delete();

                                downloadList.add(current);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (current.getOs() == OS.unknown || current.getOs() == DirUtils.getPlatform())
                            {
                                downloadList.add(current);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    threads: for (int i = 0; i < Settings.downloadThreads; i++)
                    {
                        if (downloadList.isEmpty())
                        {
                            threads = 0;
                            break threads;
                        }

                        new Thread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                ModPackFile mpFile;

                                main: while ((mpFile = getNextToDownload()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (updateBlocked())
                                    {
                                        blocked = true;
                                        break main;
                                    }

                                    if (!FileUtils.downloadFile(mpFile.getDownloadURL(modpack.setupIndex), mpFile.getSaveFile()))
                                    {
                                        LauncherLogger.log(LauncherLogger.SEVERE, "Error on downloading : " + mpFile.getDownloadURL(modpack.setupIndex));
                                    }

                                    downloaded++;

                                    Launcher.getLauncherFrame().southPanel.updateStatus(1, "", getDownloadRate(), downloaded, downloadList.size());
                                }

                                threads--;
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }

                    wait: while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (threads <= 0)
                            break wait;
                    }

                    if (!blocked)
                    {
                        FileUtils.downloadFile(modpack.modpackLink, new File(modpack.getModPackDir() + File.separator + modpack.packName + ".modpack"));
                        FileUtils.downloadFile(modpack.packBgLink, new File(modpack.getModPackDir() + File.separator + "packBg.png"));
                        FileUtils.downloadFile(modpack.modsListLink, new File(modpack.getModPackDir() + File.separator + "mods.list"));
                        Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(false);
                        GameLauncher.launchGame();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, LanguageUtils.getTranslated("launcher.modpacks.update.downloadingMapError"), LanguageUtils.getTranslated("launcher.login.warning"), JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    Launcher.setUpdatingModPack(false);
                    GameLauncher.launchGame();
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }

    private static int getDownloadRate()
    {
        double totalLength = 0.0D;
        double downloadedLength = 0.0D;
        try
        {

            for (ModPackFile f : downloadList)
            {
                totalLength += Double.valueOf(f.getSize());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < downloaded; i++)
            {
                downloadedLength += Double.valueOf(downloadList.get(i).getSize());
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return (int) ((downloadedLength * 100) / totalLength);
    }

    private static boolean updateBlocked()
    {
        if (ModPackUtils.updateStopped)
            return true;

        while (ModPackUtils.updatePaused)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static synchronized ModPackFile getNextToDownload()
    {
        int index = nextIndex++;
        return index >= downloadList.size() ? null : downloadList.get(index);
    }
}
```

I thought it was a problem of setting some functions finals but i'm not sure.
If you can't solve the problem cause too few default i can add some or could you give me just some ideas of how to solve it?

Comment: Which line of code is on line 82? That's the line where it's getting a null reference.

Comment: Launcher.getLauncherFrame().mainPanel.updateModPacks(modPacks, i != urls.size() - 1 ? false : true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is on this line:

```
Launcher.getLauncherFrame().mainPanel.updateModPacks(modPacks, i != urls.size() - 1 ? false : true);
```

a null pointer exception tends to occur when you try to access a member of a null object.  So one of the following is probably null

- Launcher.getLauncherFrame()
- Launcher.getLauncherFrame().mainPanel
- urls

I'd recommend finding a debugger, and setting a breakpoint at that area, and then looking at the state of the program to determine which of those is null.